# Python Temperature converter output is none

Tags: python, function, temperature

Im trying to create a function which will convert temperatures based on the temperature that is being converted from to the temperature which we want. However the output of my code is none when I test it.

```
def convertTemperature(T, unitFrom, unitTo):
if unitFrom=="Fahrenheit" and unitTo=="Celsius":
    T=(T-32)/1.8
    return T
elif unitFrom=="Kelvin" and unitTo=="Celcius":
    T=T-273.15
    return T
elif unitFrom=="Celcius" and unitTo=="Fahrenheit":
    T=1.8*T+32
    return T
elif unitFrom=="Kelvin" and unitTo=="Fahrenheit":
    T=1.8*T-459.67
    return T
elif unitFrom=="Celcius" and unitTo=="Kelvin":
    T=T+273.15
    return T
elif unitFrom=="Fahrenheit" and unitTo=="Kelvin":
    T=(T*459.67)/1.8
    return T
```

the unitFrom parameter is the current temperature, T is the temperature and unitTo is the temperature to which I want to convert.
I tried testing it with `print(convertTemperature(50.0, "Fahrenheit", "Celcius"))` but the output was none.

Comment: You have "Celsius" and "Celcius".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a spelling mistake `Celsius` not `Celcius`

This will work

```
def convertTemperature(T, unitFrom, unitTo):
  if unitFrom=="Fahrenheit" and unitTo=="Celsius":
      T=(T-32)/1.8
      return T
  elif unitFrom=="Kelvin" and unitTo=="Celsius":
      T=T-273.15
      return T
  elif unitFrom=="Celsius" and unitTo=="Fahrenheit":
      T=1.8*T+32
      return T
  elif unitFrom=="Kelvin" and unitTo=="Fahrenheit":
      T=1.8*T-459.67
      return T
  elif unitFrom=="Celsius" and unitTo=="Kelvin":
      T=T+273.15
      return T
  elif unitFrom=="Fahrenheit" and unitTo=="Kelvin":
      T=(T*459.67)/1.8
      return T

print(convertTemperature(50.0, "Fahrenheit", "Celsius"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you have use wrong word Celsius
It would be Celcius
Your program is right except spelling mistake